# How do I run a Metro-Application from the command-line in Windows 8?

Tags: command-line, windows-8

I'm developing an automation system and one of it's features is running applications from the command line(I mean, automatically without human intervation).

On Windows 7 I could run everything I want from a command-line call, there is some similar way to do the same with Windows 8 with also the Metro-apps installed on it?

Comment: In Windows 8, **is** there a command-line?

Comment: yes, just type cmd on the metro interface and execute it.

Comment: Are you using VS?

Comment: VS you mean Visual Studio?? No, I'm not...

Comment: FWIW, you may want to focus on Powershell instead. The AppX package includes several cmdlets for managing Metro apps (see `Get-Help Appx` for details), though I couldn't find anything for running them at the moment.

Comment: From my knowledge, you cannot run Metro apps from the command line. I hope somebody knows some hack/solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah! I found a way...

Based on [this](http://metro123.codeplex.com/releases/view/86102) source code("Open a Metro Style App from Desktop App"), I realized that I could call the metro apps just as we usually run manually. I mean, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> and go to metro's screen, you could just type the name of the metro app, such as "store" for example, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and that's it, the metro app is running. Based on this I created a very simple VBScript to do exactly these steps automatically:

> Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> objShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}"
>
> WScript.Sleep 1000
>
> objShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
>
> WScript.Sleep 1000
>
> objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Save this as "metro.vbs" and call it from the command-line with the name of the metro app on first argument:

> metro.vbs store

That is it, very simple and optimized way.

PS: All credits gave to [AlKhuzaei](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/AlKhuzaei), the Codeplex site user who created the related code. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering the same thing. Interesting solution. The only problem is if you have two programs with the same name, like both the Metro  and desktop versions of Evernote installed. Which gets launched with the above?? There should be another way since Visual Studio can launch the application you are developing.

Comment: I think that because the ctrl+esc, it will open only the metro app... It is something that would woth the test.

Comment: Nope, just tried it. [Ctrl]+[Esc] is the same as [Win], and both just show the **Start Menu**, which is allows launching any program there - Metro and Desktop alike.

Comment: So, what does Windows 8 does when two apps metro and desk have the same name??? It become duplicated on metro interface?

Comment: Yeah, it is really annoying. I uninstalled the Metro version of Evernote for precisely that reason.

Comment: Hmmm, you tried to execute the vbs command with it to see if it opens the desktop or metro? Maybe Windows will always open metro first than desktop on this specific script... (maybe :D)

Comment: Clever solution. Would be interested to see if there ends up being a more direct method eventually, but this is a cool way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The following blog post and supporting code show you how to do this with IApplicationActivationManager in PowerShell.

[Get a list of metro apps and launch them in Windows 8 using PowerShell « Tome's Land of IT](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/)

> Fortunately, I was able to find some code on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c) that showed how to use this in C# (the post also listed the registry information I will describe in this article).  After some tweaking the code and the Add-Type syntax, I was able to expose the function I needed into PowerShell.  After that it was only a matter of wrapping the function into something that resembles PowerShell.
>
> The code can be found on [poshcode](http://poshcode.org/3740).

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out another way to do it and wrote up a quick article on it at http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/

The short version: create a shortcut that points to bingnews://   You can see if it does what you want.  If so there is more instruction to get the names on the website.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to run Windows Universal apps which downloaded via Windows Store or preinstalled.
Each Windows 8/10 Universal app has an `AUMID` which stands for 'Application User Model ID'.

**PowerShell** Command to get all AUMID:

```
get-StartApps
```

Output:

> ```
> PS C:\> get-StartApps
>
> Name                      AppID
> ----                      -----
> Skype                     Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
> Snip & Sketch             Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Mail                      microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Calendar                  microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Movies & TV               Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneVideo
> Photos                    Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Video Editor              Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!SecondaryEntry
> Maps                      Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Alarms & Clock            Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Voice Recorder            Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Camera                    Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Microsoft Store           Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Weather                   Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Cortana                   Microsoft.549981C3F5F10_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Instagram                 Facebook.InstagramBeta_8xx8rvfyw5nnt!Instagram
> ...
> ```

So now, you can start any universal app via its AUMID like this:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\[AUMID]
```

For example, if you want to execute `Skype`:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
```