# Adding Windows Store apps to startup

Tags: windows-8, boot, skype, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Metro application on startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/473224/run-metro-application-on-startup)

Is there a way to add a Windows Store/Metro/Modern/Whatever app to the Windows startup?

E.g., the Skype desktop application could be set to start up with Windows.
Now I'm using the Skype app for Windows 8, and would like it to start up in a similar fashion.

Comment: This may help: (Check ekaj's answer)  http://superuser.com/questions/473224/run-metro-application-on-startup?rq=1 and also check this http://superuser.com/questions/490873/how-do-i-manage-what-programs-startup-in-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: You do realise that as soon as you start a second app, the first gets suspended?

Comment: @MamtaDalal
My questions seems to be a duplicate of your first link.
The answer seems legit, but I can't get it to work with the Skype app.
I guess I will post a new question about my new problem. Thx! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog box, then type in `msconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Go to the startup tab and click on the open Task Manager link.
You can disable or enable apps for startup from there.

You can also access the task Manager using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then selecting task manager

If you are still not able to get it follow [this old style approach](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/).

Comment: this only works for desktop apps (afaik).

Answer (score 1):

Add a script that will launch the Windows 8 Applications

We will make 2 files, one to launch the apps in general and one to launch our specific applications.
We will combine two ideas, using the [Windows 8 startup](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/) and [launching metro applications](https://superuser.com/questions/433477/how-do-i-run-a-metro-application-from-the-command-line-in-windows-8) through scripts.

1. Open a notepad document and save this script

   ```
   Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   objShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}"
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   objShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   ```
2. Make a new file called launch.bat with lines like this. Where store is the name of your app

   ```
   metro.vbs store
   ```
3. Navigate to the new startup folder at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and add your two files