# Setting Metro Remote Desktop App as Default .RDP handler

Tags: windows-8, file-association, modern-ui

Running Windows 8 with the Microsoft Store version of Remote Desktop ("Modern UI"). Ye olde Remote Desktop app is installed as well (the one like we had in Windows 7 and earlier). That older version is the default for opening .RDP. I'd like to make the Modern UI version the default.

Did some spelunking and determined that the new version is under c:\program Files\Winapps. Winapps is a folder that we are (without heroics) not allowed to browse/view/explore. That makes things difficult.

I tried using "Default Programs" to manually set the association but since I can't browse into that winApps folder I'm stymied.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/433477/270 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984786/1569

Answer (score 1):

Using the Powershell cmdlets described [here](https://superuser.com/a/498827/270), it is possible to launch the Remote Desktop app with the following command:

> Get-MetroApp |? ID -match RemoteDesktop | Start-MetroApp

If that were all there was to it then it would be possible to create a batch file or script and to make `.rdp` files open with that to cross the classic desktop/metro boundary. However it does not appear that there is any way to pass a file path to the metro Remote Desktop app, or that if *that* were possible, that the app would understand it. And even if it did, it would also need to declare file system access to read that file. Inspecting the application manifest for the current version indicates it does not.

The short answer is that this appears to not be possible.