# Launch IE in Touch Mode from Command Line

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, internet-explorer

I'm on Windows 8. How do I launch Internet Explorer in touch mode from the command line? I'm hoping for something like this:

```
iexplore /TouchMode
```

Please note, I want this to be a switch or something similar, I don't want to change the default for the app.

Comment: try this: http://superuser.com/q/433477/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 That was the first thing I tried. The accepted answer is a dirty hack. When I run it from the command line it launches desktop IE, if I double click it crashes. The other answers in that question might work for Metro only apps, but Internet Explorer is special, both the desktop and Metro versions are actually launched from the same executable, which makes me think there's got to be some sort of verb or switch to indicate which one should be launched.